# Pause a (html5) youtube video on an IOS device

Tags: javascript, ios, html, youtube, swfobject

I'm trying to pause videos with **MY OWN** buttons in a IOS UIview that has **youtube.com** loaded. I have been trying to interact with the youtube api without luck.

I'm looking at injecting my own code to interact with the player (swfobject object? Is it?). I have tried to hook up to the player/swfobject with no success. *And just to clarify again I don't want embed the videos my self in a fresh webview.* (I know how to do that. A cool way to do that is to use [Tubeplayer plugin](http://tikku.com/jquery-youtube-tubeplayer-plugin#tubeplayer_tutorial_4)).

So what I would like to do is this:

1. Inject pause JavaScript functions that I will call from my
   mobile app.
2. The function will then do something like  this:

   ```
   var theSwfobject = window.swfobject; //**Find the youtube video object for reuse.**
   theSwfobject.PauseVideo();
   ```

So the short question is: **How can I find and reuse the youtube video object on youtube.com** (so that I can inject a pause() function to call from IOS to pause the video)?

Comment: Are you sure it's an HTML5 video? Swf would seem to indicate flash. Checking out youtube, the video loaded as flash on my browser. They might have progressive enhancement to HTML5, but I'm not convinced since my browser supports HTML5 video. I think you are looking for how to pause a Flash video.

Comment: If it is indeed an HTML5 video, it should be a <video> element in the DOM. Once you have that element just call element.pause() or element.play() which are the HTML5 api methods for those actions on an HTML5 video object. Why are you grabbing a swfobject instead of the video element?

Comment: It might be right that its not a HTML5 video at all. I´m using the iOS 5.1 version that still had the "override flash videos because they are dangerous and show them in the apple player". Now in the newer version 6.0 and up, apple still banns flash but doesn´t show the videos so a hmtl5 video is needed. The new swf 2.0 supports that. It finds out what format is supported (default is flash) and writes out the player. I was expecting html5 but thats probably wrong of me. Now Im updating the iOS and if that works I´ll know if you are correct.

Comment: Ok I updated the iOS and now I get a <video> element but I'm unsure how to interact with it. This is what i get <video class="video-stream html5-main-video" x-webkit-airplay="allow" data-youtube-id="Vb1pdvvoVoQ" src="http://r1---sn-aigezn7r.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?id=55…..." style="width: 685px; height: 385px; left: 0px; top: 14px; "></video> [Here](http://www.steveworkman.com/html5-2/javascript/2012/interacting-with-html5-video-players/) is an example of youtube html5 interaction.

Comment: Great, that looks like HTML5 video now. When you say 'this is what I get <video ...' are you getting this as viewing source or as a JavaScript DOM element object? If the second case, you should be able to make a call to the pause() function on that object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your latest comment I would expect to do something in JavaScript. Here is a little API I would setup to control the video element in this instance. Since the video element doesn't seem to have an id, used getElementsByTagName:

```
var myVideoController = {};

myVideoController = (function() {

  "use strict";      

  var muted = false;

  var module = {

    //Grabs video element by tag name and assumes there would only be one if it exists 
    getVideoElement : function() {
      var videoElements = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
      var videoElement = null;

      if(videoElements[0]) {
        videoElement = videoElements[0];
      }

      return videoElement;
    },

    /** 
     * Wrapper to make interacting with html5 video element functions easier.
     * @param functionName - name of function to invoke on the video element
     * @params - any additional parameters will be fed as arguments to the functionName function
     */
    callVideoFunction : function(functionName) {
      var videoElement = module.getVideoElement();
      var functionArguments = [];

      if(videoElement !== null) {
        functionArguments = module.getSubArguments(arguments, 1);

        if(functionArguments.length > 0) {
          videoElement[functionName](functionArguments);
        } else {
          videoElement[functionName]();
        }
      }
    },

    setVideoProperty : function(propertyName, propertyValue) {
      var videoElement = module.getVideoElement();

      if(videoElement !== null) {
        videoElement[propertyName] = propertyValue;
      }
    },

    /* Helper method to grab array of function arguments for callVideoFunction
       since the arguments object in functions looks like an array but isn't
       so .shift() is not defined */
    getSubArguments : function (args, indexFrom) {

      var subArguments = [];

      for(var i = indexFrom; i < args.length; i++) {
        subArguments.push(args[i]);
      }

      return subArguments;
    },

    //Pause the video
    pauseVideo : function() {
      module.callVideoFunction('pause');
    },

    //Play the video
    playVideo : function() {
      module.callVideoFunction('play');
    },

    //Mute/Unmute video
    flipVideoMute : function() {
      muted = !muted;
      module.setVideoProperty('muted', muted);
    }
  };

  return module;

})();
```

I tested it at http://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html where w3 has set up an HTML5 video with feedback on the api usage. I copied the above code into the javascript console and ran commands as follows:

```
//Start video
myVideoController.playVideo();

//Pause video
myVideoController.pauseVideo();

//Restart video
myVideoController.playVideo();

//Mute video
myVideoController.flipVideoMute();

//Unmute video
myVideoController.flipVideoMute();
```